# Warning: Error in print: trying to get slot "..." from an object (class "reactivevalues") that is not an S4 object

Tags: r, shiny

In a shiny module, I have the following pickerInput()

```
pickerInput(inputId = ns('zebra'), label = NULL, choices = c("Truck", "Train", "Barge", "Shipment"))
```

In the server of this module I try to fetch this value with:

```
  input@zebra %>% print()
```

And this produces the following error:

```
Warning: Error in print: trying to get slot "zebra" from an object (class "reactivevalues") that is not an S4 object
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a typo in the line of code in the server, which should have been:

```
input$zebra %>% print()
```

Thus a `$`instead of a `@`. I just overlooked it for a few hours.